Error: Activity class {com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity} does not exist when running yarn android in React Native
I am working on a React Native project and encountered the following error when running yarn android:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 22s  
473 actionable tasks: 26 executed, 447 up-to-date  
info Connecting to the development server...  
info Starting the app on "MV994PT495UCLB7H"...  
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.app/.MainActivity }  
Error type 3  
Error: Activity class {com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity} does not exist.  

Steps I've Tried:

Device Setup:


My laptop and mobile are connected via USB and are on the same Wi-Fi network.


Cleaning and Uninstalling:


Ran ./gradlew uninstallAll and retried.
Deleted the build folder in the android directory.
Tried ./gradlew clean.


ADB Commands:


Executed adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081.
Ran adb uninstall .
MainActivity and Package Name Check:


Verified that the package name in android/app/src/main/java/com/example/app/MainActivity.kt matches the applicationId in android/app/build.gradle under defaultConfig.

Emulator and Device Checks:



Tried running on both a physical device and an emulator but faced the same issue.
Wiped the data of the emulator and created a new emulator instance.
Repository Checks:


Deleted the project, cloned it again, and retried.
Confirmed with teammates that the repository is working for them, so the issue seems specific to my setup.

Other Attempts:


Restarted VS Code and my laptop.
Additional Info:
The project was working fine earlier on my setup.
It's currently running fine for my teammates.
Does anyone have insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Sometimes when testing on a device or you have a multi user setup, the app doesn't uninstall properly. To verify and fix this:
Goto Mobile Settings > Apps > [Your App] > More(top right menu) > Uninstall App for All Users.
if this does not solve your issue,
kindly share java and node versions you are using
you can get them by running following command in project folder
    npx react-native info


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
